# Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « simplement » avec « tout bêtement » ?

Tags: étymologie

Comment « [tout bêtement](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/tout%20b%C3%AAtement) » a-t-il glissé sémantiquement à signifier « simplement » ?

Answer (score 1):

**Bêtement** signifie étymologiquement « à la manière d'une bête, d'un animal déraisonnable ».

Le contraire est donc « à la manière d'un être humain, avec intelligence ».

Il est alors assez naturel d'associer ce qui est simple, évident à « bêtement » par opposition à ce qui est intelligent, complexe, hors de portée des bêtes « stupides ».

L'adverbe *tout* accentue le fait qu'il s'agit de quelque chose de simple et/ou d'un peu stupide.